# Filter columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

From world database available right here http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/world.sql.gz I want to display only the names of the countries speaking more than 5 languages :

I've tried this:

```
SELECT 
    country.Name, COUNT(countrylanguage.Language) as languages
FROM 
    country, countrylanguage
WHERE 
    country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode 
GROUP BY 
    country.Name
HAVING 
    languages >= 6
```

But the problem is that is it shows the number of languages as well, what I want is only the column `country.Name`.

Thank you.

Comment: It is better practice to use ANSI style joins....

Comment: just remove `COUNT(countrylanguage.Language) as languages`
and replace `languages` after `HAVING` with `COUNT(countrylanguage.Language)`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Answer from TinTran's comment :

`SELECT country.Name
FROM country, countrylanguage
WHERE country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode 
Group BY country.Name
HAVING COUNT(countrylanguage.Language) >= 6`

Comment: you forgot the ansi style joins

Answer (score 1):

with ANSI style INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT country.Name
FROM country INNER JOIN countrylanguage
ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode 
Group BY country.Name
HAVING COUNT(countrylanguage.Language) >= 6
```